# "Try Ubuntu without installing" option from bootable USB with Ubuntu 19.10 crashes suddenly

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, usb

I am trying to make a dual boot on my SSD. I have Windows 10 in one partition installed and I want to install Ubuntu 19.10 on the other.

I created a bootable USB drive with the Ubuntu 19.10 image. When I boot my laptop by the USB drive, I select the option "Try Ubuntu without installing". The system apparently boots as normal, but after 1-2 minutes, it just crashes.

Choosing the option "Try Ubuntu without installing (safe graphics)" fix the problem mentioned above, but then when I try actually installing Ubuntu, I can't see the buttons on the window because it expands outside of the screen and there's no way I can drag it to make the buttons visible, so I can't proceed on the installation wizard.

My laptop is a MSI with:
i7-8750H 2.20GHz processor
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 graphics card

Comment: What happens if you don't use "Try Ubuntu" and install directly?

Comment: @MelcomX the same, after around 1-2 minutes on the installation wizard it just crashes

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, install the system, then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 booting with nomodset leads to the same issue where I can’t see the buttons on the window